# How to enable the scheduler in spring boot based on the static variable at runtime?

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler

Here are the details,

I have two schedulers with @scheduled Annotation. Let's says A & B. "A" Scheduler does some job and set value in static variable using setter. I want to enable the "B" Scheduler only the static variable is set to true.

One solution, I know is to the check/validate the static variable flag in "B" scheduler and skip the further process but the scheduler checks every time based on interval specified (i.e., fixed delay).

I want to completely disable the scheduler based on static variable at run time value.

PS : I manually set the time delay between the "A" & "B" Schedulers. So "A" runs first then "B"

For Example:

Initialize.class

```
        Configuration 
        EnableScheduling 
        public class Initialize { 
        
        public A a{ 
        return new A(); 
          } 
        
        public B b{ 
        return new B(); 
          } 
        }
```

A.class

```
    public class A{
        
        Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "sometime specified")
        public void aProcessor(){ 
        // Following code sets the value of static variable like       staticClass.setAppVariable(true); 
          } 
        }
```

B.class

```
     public class B{
        
        Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "sometime specified")
        public void bProcessor(){ 
        // some process        
          } 
        }
```

static.class

```
        public class staticClass implements Serializable{
        
        private static volatile boolean appVariable = false;
        
            public static boolean getAppVariable() {
                return appVariable;
            }
            public static void setAppVariable(boolean appVariable) {
                staticClass.appVariable = appVariable;
            }
        
        }
```

But I need to initialise the "B" class/scheduler based on the static variable if it is true.

Any help?

Comment: You could start/stop the scheduler programmatically

Comment: You could use a timer

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Could you please let me know in details or any snippet?

Comment: @mystery How to make use of timer? becoz static variable is being set my other scheduler.

Comment: @SandeepKumarManda please show your code segment otherwise it is hard to understand

Comment: @mystery Okies.

I have a configuration class

Configuration
EnableScheduling
public class InitializeSchedulers {
public A a{
return new A();
}

public B b{
return new B();
}
}

public class A{
Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "sometime specified")
public void aProcessor(){
// Following code sets the value of static variable like SomeClass.setvariable(true);
}
}

B class have some process to do. 

But I need to initialise the scheduler based on the static variable is true.

Hope u understand my problem.

Comment: @SandeepKumarManda pls add the code in question description with proper formatting. Also where is your static variable?

Comment: @mystery - Edited the posted as requested.